# Fetch data from two MYSql tables and display as HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, the first is a 'users' table which has a column called 'store' and I also have a table called 'stores' with columns 'store number' 'store location'.

The column 'store' in the users table is a 'store number'.

What I'm trying to do is create a HTML table that is something like

Sample data:

Store number: 34
Store location: London
Users: 34

Store Number | Store Location | Number of Users at this store|

So it would be something like select * from stores and for each create new row.

and for the number of users be something like sum * from users where 'store' = 'store number' from stores table.

I hope this makes sense,

Jack.

UPDATE:

This is correct:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores", $con) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Store Number</th> <th>Store Location</th> <th>Number of Users</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['storenumber'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo 'Amount of users here';
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `storenumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (

```
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `store` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastvisit` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

Comment: One second i will update....

Comment: Please update with tables structure and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT storenumber, location, COUNT(users.store) as nbr_users FROM stores
LEFT JOIN users ON stores.storenumber = users.store
GROUP BY store.id
```

and then do

```
echo $row['nbr_users'];
```

to print the number of users.

Comment: I have updated my solution. See sqlfiddle here also: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7a28/3

Comment: Please update the question with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your two tables. And first you write `2 with '140'` and then `'140' is not showing`??

Comment: I updated the SQL again, please use `COUNT(users.store)` as above.

Comment: Updated my post with create tables, your count update didnt change anything :(

Comment: `users` table is missing the `store` field in your table.. Also I changed `GROUP BY` operator to unique `id` field, may help with your missing 140.

Comment: That was just a mistake when typing, I have updated that now. Update group by but still missing that store

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22242/discussion-between-jack-and-erik-ekman)

Comment: The missing item was solved be removing the first $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result ); as the while loop then called it again missing the first result!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores", $con) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Store Number</th> <th>Store Location</th> <th>Number of Users</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // gets the total amount of users
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users WHERE `store`='".$row['storenumber']."'") or die( mysql_error() );
    $r = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
    $total = $r['total'];
    unset($query, $r);

    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['storenumber'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $total;
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
$result = mysql_query("Select count(user_id) as CNT,storenumber,location from store Left join user ON user.store_number = store.store_number group by store.store_number", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result );

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Store Number</th> <th>Store Location</th> <th>Number of Users</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['storenumber'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['CNT'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

If you can provide with exact table structure i can frame it more accurately.

Comment: `SUM()` will give the sum of userids, not the number of them. Userid 1 and 2 will give 3 in this example.